# Bluetooth switches off by itself

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

I use a bluetooth speaker with my laptop (Dell Inspiron 5547). When I connect the speaker, it works for about 20 minutes perfectly, and then Ubuntu's bluetooth switches off by itself, and I'm unable to switch it back on. This has happened several times now.

How do I fix this?

*Note: There are solutions available currently for bluetooth that won't switch on at all. My bluetooth works for about 20 minutes with my speaker and then turns off by itself.*

There is no issue with my speaker or bluetooth connectivity. It works perfectly in Windows 10.